# Avoiding edges using GRASS generalization?

Tags: grass-gis, generalization, parallel-processing

I'm trying to process the national wide land cover data into vector polygons.

In order to be quick I separate the data into several tiles and process them in parallel.

process flow is :
1. v.in.ogr
2. v.generalize douglas method
3. v.generalize chaiken method
4. v.out.ogr shapefile

But the result is the eages of each tile's topology isn't correct as before. it has holes in it. see the picture below

**Is there any way to run chaiken generalize in parallel and avoid the edges being modified?**

[image]

Comment: Any chance to avoid the tiling? Or, at least minimize it?